# Force a perforce server to have exactly what you have in workspace

Tags: version-control, perforce, synchronization

Heylo guys,

is there a way to force a perforce server to have exactly what you have in workspace.

ie:

- workspace : file A' B C
- perforce: file A B D E F

these files are not checked out, imagine C was deleted by OS
perforce then **automatically** creates a changelist that removes D, E, F and add C and edit A

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your particular case, you can create the changelist with:

```
p4 edit A
p4 delete D E F
p4 add C
```

After creating the changelist, don't forget to submit it:

```
p4 submit -d "what I changed and why"
```

The generic method of creating a changelist requires a script:

```
p4 diff -se | p4 -x- edit
p4 diff -sd | p4 -x- delete
find . -type f | p4 -x- add
```